# Where to find approach plates for European aerodromes?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, eu

Where do I find the approach plates for European aerodromes? Is there a website intended for pilots updated and certified from the authority?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eurocontrol has the charts for all participating countries. You'll need to register for a free account.

https://eadbasic.ead-it.com/cms-eadbasic/opencms/en/login/ead-basic/

"The EAD Basic solution is specifically targeted at:

- private pilots and general aviation;
- members of the public searching for aeronautical information;
- training schools;
- everyone who has an interest in aviation and aeronautical information."

Answer (score 1):

Google the intended country for its [eAIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeronautical_Information_Publication#Electronic_AIP). The charts will be official. (May or may not be free; may or may not require registration.)

Free public access for the UK, as an example, can be found here: [nats-uk.ead-it.com](http://www.nats-uk.ead-it.com/public/index.php%3Foption=com_content&task=blogcategory&id=6&Itemid=13.html)